# Securing my wireless network

Tags: security, wireless-networking

At home I have a wireless network that I have my notebook, Zune, PS3, etc connected to.

I've set it up using WPA2 with AES encryption, a 63-character alphanumeric & symbols key, MAC filtering for all my devices and I've disabled SSID broadcast.

Yes, I live in an apartment complex and yes, you could call me paranoid. To be fair, in the past I've received one of those cease-and-desist letters for online piracy. So I really want to make sure no one is on my network without me knowing about it.

**Am I as protected as possible or is there more I could do to secure my network?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I can't think of more that you could do. You've avoided the big mistakes of wireless "security", being:

- using WEP;
- using no security;
- relying on client MAC filtering; and
- relying on no SSID broadcast.

None of these is secure and none you're doing. There is no better readily available wireless encryption standard than WPA2 currently.

Comment: Seems pretty reasonable to me

Comment: I can't think of anything else either.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds great. I've started running my networks through a [WifiDog](http://dev.wifidog.org/) server to make people login. This allows me to track bandwidth and usage very well. I really like it and it's especially helpful when you want an open network that still needs to have accountability. (I install dd-wrt on all of my routers so it's a snap to setup).

So basically, you could setup a portal style system but I think that's unnecessary based on what you've done.