# How to protect my wirless LAN from mobile hacking apps?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, security

Good day to you,I have a TP-Link wireless L3 broadband switch (commonly called a router), I have SSID broadcast disabled and WPA2 and firewall enabled. However, somehow people in the area are using hacking apps on their mobile devices to gain access to my network. I have a 15 character password with letters, numbers, and symbols. [This thread](https://superuser.com/questions/2572/securing-my-wireless-network) suggests using WPA2 with AES encryption pre-shared key, which I already am. Am I missing something? Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry for misleading you, I meant they are using apps on their mobile devices to hack into my wireless LAN

Comment: @Ramhound KRACK exploits the *client* side of the handshake. You have to patch your *clients*. Also, KRACK doesn’t let attackers join your network. You’re spreading dangerous misconceptions here.

Comment: @SamIbraheem What evidence do you have that people are joining your network? If you just saw unknown devices in Windows’ “Network” window, beware that it can show nearby Wi-Fi devices that are NOT on your network. It does that in case you want to have Windows help get those devices onto your network via WPS. Disabling WPS on your routers should make these unconnected devices stop showing up. There’s also a Windows service you can stop if you want to go that route instead.

Comment: @Spiff - I originally indicated that WPA2 wasn't vulnerable to anything except a brute force attack.  I deleted that statement because I suddenly remembered KRACK was recently discovered.  I then indicated that the author would either have to wait for a patch from TP-Link or use a third-party firmware.  For a vulnerability that cannot be used against an access point, the Open-WRT and LEDE community discussion on KRACK, sure didn't give me that impression.  In any event the router should still be patched.  **Comments removed.**

Answer (score -2):

I'd recommend changing the network channel to to channel 13 as it ensures more stealth for your network.  For added security from such apps and hacks you should enable MAC address filtering on your network and run regular scans to check for unauthorized access and you can disable their connections using NetCut or WifiKill, And you are good to go.

Comment: -1 This spreads a dangerous misconception about KRACK. KRACK exploits the *client* side of the key handshake. You must patch your *clients*. Patching an AP-capable box is only necessary if the AP-capable box is a multifunction box that is also set up to act as a client.

Comment: Also, KRACK doesn’t allow attackers to learn your network’s password or join the network. So that’s another harmful misconception this spreads.